# Using values from .txt file in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm kinda lost on how to use constant values from an external *.txt* file in my python file

**File.txt:**

```
email=value1
phone=value2
name=value3
```

And I want to use these values on my python file.

I have tried to do this:

```
Data = open('file.txt', 'r')
data1= Data.read(email)
print(data1)
```

But it isn't working as expected, expected output is "Value1". But I  get an error, and if I only do `Data.read()` I am getting:

```
email=value1
phone=value2
name=value3
```

How would I get each value separately to use them in my python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what are you looking for, but here's something that might help you:

```py
# Open the file for read
Data = open('file.txt', 'r')

# Reading the data from file
data1 = {}
for line in Data.readlines():
    key, val = line.strip().split("=")  # strip() removes "\n" at the end of each line
    data1[key] = val                    # Placing key,val in dictionary


# Using the data
email = data1['email']

# Don't forget to close the file
Data.close()
```

Comment: It's better to use `with`. Why? Read [Python: Open a file using “open with” statement & benefits explained with examples](https://thispointer.com/python-open-a-file-using-open-with-statement-benefits-explained-with-examples/) article from thispointer.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data1 = dict(zip([i.strip().split('=') for i in file.readlines() if i]))
    print(data1['email'])
```

Output:

```
value1
```

Comment: `File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    data1 = dict(zip([i.strip().split('=') for i in file]))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` Im getting this

Comment: @Pepee Can you show me your entire txt file?

Comment: its basically as i put in the post, file is named "file.txt" and inside is `email=value1
phone=value2
name=value3` in 3 different lines, Python program called Test.py has exactly the code you provided

Comment: Still not working, But appreciate your help though. @ Almog answer works great

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from @U12-Forward, working and tried to describe what we are doing:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = dict([i.split('=') for i in f.read().splitlines()])
    print(data["email"]) # value1
    print(data['phone']) # value2
```

What we are doing is, using `f.read()` reading file and splitting the `f.read()` into list from linebreak(`\n`) and looping through that list and again splitting those each lines with `=` and making `list` and then at last `dict`.

If it is harder for you to understand then you can split these lines like this, made easier to understand:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    read=f.read()
    data={}
    for i in read.splitlines():
        x=i.split("=")
        data.update(dict([x]))
    print(data["email"]) # value1
    print(data['phone']) # value2
```

**Additionally:**

You can use,change and do anything after this:

```
data["email"]="test@.."
print(data["email"]) # test@..

email=data["email"]
# Now you can use this email variable as your python variable.
```